# What do we mean when we say instance?

Tags: java, oop

If we have class B that extends class A, and we have the following code:

```
A obj = new B();
```

Is obj variable refers to instance of A or B?

Comment: It is both but only the fields/methods of A are accessible. A doctor helps animals. He does not always care if it is a cat or a dog. While it is important to the specific treatment to know if it is a cat or a dog, it is fine to only know that it is an animal to make an appointment. Technically, the concrete instance is of the concrete type B. But as it inherits A this implies it is also an A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is obj variable refers to instance of A or B?

Both!

If you own a cat, do you own a cat or an animal? -- You can rightfully say you own both!

Paraphrased in code:

```
Animal a = new Cat();
```

`a` is a variable that holds a reference to a `Cat` object (which at the same time is an `Animal` object).

So...
...does `a` hold a reference to a `Cat`? Yes.
...does `a` hold a reference to an `Animal`? Yes.